# Database table columns missing in MySqlWorkBench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am working with mysql workbench 5.2.47 on Mac. I have created new database, table and some columns in the table. Sometimes, when I open this database (connection is fine) in mysql workbench, it is not showing any columns that I created under the table. But, if i close and open mysql workbench multiple times, and then its displaying the columns under that table. It is not happening always, but sometimes only it is not showing any columns that I created under the table.
I couldn't any find solution or workaround what to do this to get the actual columns displayed under the table.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXVQG.png) for reference:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Solved! Seems like a lot of people are stuck in this odd situation.
There is an easy solution to this.
Hover abbove the "Object Info" and "Session" and your cursor will change to split arrows. Then all you have to do is drag it downward and it will reveal the hidden sidebar with Management, Schemas etc.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

I, personally, faced this problem only when I was disconnected from the server. So, when you try to execute an SQL query you receive an error like:

> "Error Code: 2006. MySQL server has gone away."

Go to the option "Query" and then "Reconnect to Server," or simply close the connection and open it again. If yours happens to be the same case as that of mine, you should be able to get the columns displayed again.

Answer (score -1):

Click the little "Refresh" icon (to the right of Schemas). Also, upgrade to Workbench 6.1.x as the 5.2 branch is no longer maintained.

Comment: Refresh didn't helped, i tried already. I need to restart my mac machine to get this one back. But, looking for some solution rather than restarting the machine.

Comment: Why not try a (much) newer version of Workbench?